# Ag Grid Angular Master Detail hide nested grid when no data

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a master detail Ag Grid with two sublevels.

How to hide a 2nd or 3rd level grid if there is no data ?

below is the Plunkr and code for detailcellrendering

```
public detailCellRendererParams: any = {
    // level 2 grid options
    detailGridOptions: {
      headerHeight: 0,
      columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Name', editable: true, cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' }
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
      },
      groupDefaultExpanded: 1,
      masterDetail: true,
      detailRowHeight: 240,
      detailCellRendererParams: {
        // level 3 grid options
        detailGridOptions: {
          headerHeight: 0,
          columnDefs: [
            { field: 'RegionName', editable: true, cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer' },
          ],
          defaultColDef: {
            flex: 1,
          },
        },
        getDetailRowData: (params) => {
          debugger;
          var attr = [];
          params.successCallback(params.data.Regions);
        },
      } as IDetailCellRendererParams,
    },
    getDetailRowData: (params) => {
      debugger;
      params.successCallback(params.data.States);
      //params.node.setExpanded(false);
    },
  } as IDetailCellRendererParams;
```

[Plunk Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8hXofKn1jJ6Z6aU)